# Sharekit Base Sharer gets deallocated

Tags: ios, facebook, email, sharing, sharekit

I have integrated Sharekit 2.5.7. It works without errors. It shows the UI for the same. But after selecting any particular option I get an error.

For eg. If I select Email as the Sharing medium I get a message called "Email sharer deallocated!!!" and nothing happens. Similar is the case with Facebook.

Please help!!!

Comment: That message is informative only. It is for debugging purposes, that sharer is properly deallocated after share. Must be something else. I can not reproduce the error. Could you step through the code? What view are you showing the UI from? Is it still alive during share?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who experiences this.

Make sure you follow step 7 exactly found below

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-ShareKit

I added a sharekit methood to the wrong place and it caused the issue the OP experienced, hope this helps someone else.